# C++ OpenGL (freeglut)

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to pass a object reference from a function on the main method. I think the problem lies in there.

In java I would do something like this:

```
Object obj;

theFunction(obj);
```

the method definition would be like:

```
public void theFunction(Object obj) {
    obj.useMethod();
}
```

What I did on c++ was:

```
void theFunction(Object& obj){
    obj.useMethod();
}
```

This way is what I believe is correct accordingly to what I have been reading on the subject. I am using visual studio 2013 and it does not complain, only when I compile. The error message is as follows:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Radiosity, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall    Keyboard::specialKeys(class Camera &)" (?specialKeys@Keyboard@@QAEXAAVCamera@@@Z)   referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
1>C:\Users\PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Radiosity\Debug\Radiosity.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having a linkage error.

`Keyboard::specialKeys()` is somewhere declared on your code. So it means, you are using a correct header file when compiling your code. But you are not linking to the correct library.

Which library does `Keyboard::specialKeys()` comes from? You need it in order to correct the linkage of your program.

In Visual Studio, right click on your project and go to the Project Settings (or something like), then

> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependences

Add in this field the correct library file. A .lib file corresponding to the `Keyboard::specialKeys()`

Comment: OMG, I can't believe I missed that. I have two similar methods.
I forgot to put Keyboard:: in front of the method declaration.
Thanks man! I accept your answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would double check the links to the libraries. The code looks fine to me. I had a hell of a time setting up an OpenGL context the first time I started using it.

Also check out these pages on the specific errors:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z98k84c3.aspx

Comment: msdn is not an official source of information for OpenGL, furthermore, Microsoft is the rivalry and has performed a lot of actions to destroy/slow-down OpenGL.

Comment: Well, those are the specific compiler errors. They are using a Microsoft IDE, so I don't know where else you could possibly go to find those error codes. Those errors weren't because of OpenGL, they were from Visual Studio, and they are generic link errors.